# Uninitialized constant SQLite error

Tags: ruby, sqlite, nameerror

As soon as I add code to access my .sqlite database, I get a strange error:

```
in 'total': uninitialized constant Test2::SQLite (NameError)
```

My code is as follows:

Test1.rb

```
require_relative 'Test2.rb'

co = Test2.new()
price = co.total
```

Test2.rb

```
require 'sqlite3'

class Test2

    def initialize()
            @items = []
    end

    def total()
        db = SQLite::Database.open "Database.sqlite"
        db.close()
        return 0
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SQLite` module doesn't exist, but it is named `SQLite3` ([check the docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.6/frames)):

```
require 'sqlite3'

class Test2

    def initialize()
            @items = []
    end

    def total()
        db = SQLite3::Database.open "Database.sqlite"
        db.close()
        return 0
    end
end
```

Comment: It happens every once in a while... at least to me :)